# Сокеты.Клиент-сервер

Tags: java, c#, websocket, socket.io

Здравствуйте, моя задача реализовать клиент-серверное приложение. Сервер на С#, клиент на Java (Android). Когда мне просто нужно сделать запрос на сервер, отослать с клиента на сервер инфу и получить ответ - то проблем нет. Но если мне нужно от Сервера сделать посыл на клиента, отправить с Сервера на клиент? Грамотно ли в таком случае слать каждые, например, 3-4 секунды с клиента месседж, и парсить также сразу ответ от сервера, или есть другие красивые способы? Просто запрос на сервер логически понятен, мы знаем  ip-адрес и порт и коннектимся к нему, а когда нужно наоборот с сервера передать инфу на клиент, неужто клиент должен постоянно периодически делать запрос на сервак, чтобы отслеживать изменение ответа?

Comment: Используй для этого SignalR.

Comment: Стоит тег websocket, значит вы о нём знаете. Так почему задаёте такой вопрос? Вот через вебсокет сервер и будет слать данные клиенту самостоятельно.

Comment: Походу не знаю(

Comment: Пожалуйста , пример какой нибудь.

Comment: Просто на с# сервер Десктопная прога, а клиент на android приложении, а websocket если не ошибаюсь только по браузерам как бы?

Comment: Все просто - узнаете id клиента > дергаете его и отправляете ему что-то.

Comment: нет, не все просто. и вы это поймете очень быстро, когда почитаете про динамические айпишники, которые с вероятностью 99,9 процента у клиента. оповещение сервером своего состояния - очень сложная задача, обусловдено это тем, что мы пользуемся HTTP v1.1, а в нем есть только Request - Response. Я бы советовал Вам разобраться с этими базовыми понятиями перед тем, как перейти к использованию таких вещей, как, например, websocket

Comment: может быть push?)

Comment: @GoodRA websocket работает с андроидом на ура и без проблем (если не считать потребление из-за постоянной работы, даже в режиме сервиса). У меня сервер на java работал по ws одновременно и с браузером и с андроидом (приложение) . с ws стоит разобраться один раз - потом наслаждаться . сделал трекер для отображения положения смартфона на карте гугла -работало в реальном времени очень шикарно